# Excel data validation with both forced values and user selection

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, named-ranges

Goal: allow the user to select from a drop-down list of values in a particular cell, but not if a value of another cell is a specific value.

I'm trying to use Data Validation with Excel lists (Data > Data Validation > Select list and either enter the named list range or a manually typed list) to force specific values from the user, but the values in the drop-down list should depend on other cell values. [I found this site](https://exceljet.net/formula/data-validation-with-conditional-list) that explains how to do conditional lists. What I want to do is something like that, but force a specific value in cell B if A contains a specific value. Example:

- A1 has Data Validation that allows either "Work" or "Shopping"
- B1 also has Data Validation that allows either "Weekend" or "Weekday"
- If A1 contains "Shopping" then B1 can be either "Weekend" or "Weekday"
- If A1 contains "Work", then B1 should be forced to "Weekday"

I tried to create two named ranges for B1, one called "AnyDay" with both Weekend/Weekday, and one called "WeekdayOnly" with only Weekday. In B1, I then add a Data Validation List with the following:

```
=IF(A1="Work",WeekdayOnly,AnyDay)
```

This only achieves the data validation but does not update the value of B1 depending on A1. As in, if A1 is set to "Shopping", B1 is set to "Weekend", and I then change A1 to "Work", B1 remains at "Weekend". If I click on the drop-down, the available options are correctly displaying "Weekday" only, but the current value remains "Weekend".

Is there a way to, using data validation and/or other tools, either force a specific value or allow a drop-down list for the user to select from?

Comment: You need then vba to clear `B1` cell data.

Comment: I was afraid it would be something like that, you don't happen to know if it's possible to do without VBA?

Comment: To build on Harun`s comment, validation can't change an already existing value, it can only restrict entry of a new value.  To change an existing value, you'll need VBA.  Perhaps a Worksheet_Change event

Comment: I was thinking if I could do something like =IF(A1="Work","Weekday",some conditional formula/list allowed here), but I assume then that VBA is necessary regardless?

Comment: You can change the list data dependent on condition, but you can't change a previous chosen value based on a drop-down value. Not without VBA.

Comment: :( okay then, I guess I'll have to delve into VBA :) thanks for the help!